# how to get coordinate for every point in lattice with py?

Tags: python, scripting, coordinates

```
import bpy

act_obj = bpy.context.active_object

u = act_obj.data.points_u 
v = act_obj.data.points_v
w = act_obj.data.points_w
points_sum = u*v*w - 1

while(points_sum != 0):
    pt_pos = act_obj.data.points[points_sum].co
    print(points_sum, 'coordinat',pt_pos)
    points_sum = points_sum - 1
```

I need to get coordinates of all points to create in their position bones, like controllers for lattice.

Comment: Can you explain what the current code does and how it differs from what you want?

Comment: 7 coordinat <Vector (0.5000, -0.5000, 32.5000)>
6 coordinat <Vector (-0.5000, -0.5000, 32.5000)>
5 coordinat <Vector (0.5000, 0.5000, 31.5000)>
4 coordinat <Vector (-0.5000, 0.5000, 31.5000)>
3 coordinat <Vector (0.5000, -0.5000, 31.5000)>
2 coordinat <Vector (-0.5000, -0.5000, 31.5000)>
1 coordinat <Vector (0.5000, 0.5000, 30.5000)>

that is result of my code
but that is vector, but not point coordinate!

Comment: i need to detect lattice point for for create in their coord new bone, for hook

Comment: http://prntscr.com/et9c2b

Comment: If you need to add extra information to your question you can use the [edit] link below it.